# Scrapy is skipping first page in pagination

Tags: pagination, scrapy

The following Scrapy CrawlSpider class code is for scraping links via following pagination from the `data.ok.gov` page.

```
class OklahomaFinanceSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "OklahomaFinanceSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["data.ok.gov"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://data.ok.gov/browse?f[0]=bundle_name%3ADataset&f[1]=im_field_categories%3A4191"
        ] 

    rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//li[@class="pager-next"]',)), callback="parse_page", follow= True),
) 
def parse_page(self, response): 

        for href in response.xpath('//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "),"search-results apachesolr_search-results")]/h3/a/@href'):
        url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)
```

However, the first page is not being scraped. What mistake am I making with the Rules?

Comment: If you're talking about parsing the pages fetched from the `start_urls`, check [`parse_start_url`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider.parse_start_url). You can set `parse_start_url = parse_page` and you should be good

Comment: I did add parse_start_url = parse_page after defining the rules, but in terminal, the error was "NameError: name 'parse_page' is not defined" . Any idea why I am getting it?

Comment: you can set `parse_start_url = parse_page` *after* the `def parse_page(self, response):` block

Answer (score 0):

Posting [@paul trmbrth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2572383/paul-trmbrth) comment as an answer here.

For parsing the pages fetched at the `start_urls`, set `parse_start_url = parse_page after` after the `parse_page(self, response)` definition.